# Prime factors of $p-1$

Tags: sieve-theory

It is one of the consequences of Sieve theory is that number of primes $p\leq x$ such that all prime divisors of $p-1$ are greater than $p^{\varepsilon},$ is $\gg \frac{x}{\log^2x}.$ In particular, all of these $p-1$ have a bounded number of prime divisors. Due to Halberstam we know, number of distinct prime factors of $p-1$ is $\log \log p$ on an average. Given a constant $c$, is it known how many primes are there up-to $x$ such that all number of distinct prime factors of $p-1$ is bounded by $c$ ? I feel this actually same as answering the $p^{\varepsilon}$ thing, is it ?

Comment: No, not quite. The lower bound that you produce from the sieve has the wrong order of magnitude. You should look for papers on the Titchmarsh divisor problem. Also, the first sentence is wrong: for almost all primes $p$ the smallest prime divisor of $p - 1$ is $2$.

Comment: You are right, yes I should have said odd prime factors. But what's the correct order ? is it like $c\frac{x}{\log x}$ for some $0<c<1$ ?